# SQL query: find game for user where game's current_player is NULL, author of the last card in game is not user, and game has not been seen by user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Short database schema:

- users (id)
- games (current_player_id) // has many cards
- cards (author_id, game_id, content, created_at)
- game_views(game_id, user_id) //shows which games user have seen

I need to find game for **user**, which meets all whose rules:

1. game's current_player is NULL (the game do not played by anybody right now)
2. author of the last card in game(order by created_at, I think) is not **user**
3. game have not been seen by **user**

I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the most clear solution. With proper indexes, performance should be reasonable but its not going to scale well if the number of games gets into the millions. If that happens, one way to increase performance would be to store the last card_id at the game level.

```
select game_id
FROM game g
WHERE g.current_player is null
AND not exists (select 0 from game_view gv 
             where gv.user_id = v_my_user_id and gv.game_id = g.game_id)
AND not exists (select 0 from 
    (select author_id from cards c where c.game_id = g.game_id order 
    by created_at LIMIT 1) 
    t1 where t1.author_id =  v_my_user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this code with SQL Server in mind, but it should work in Postgres. If it doesn't, the differences should be minimal afaik.

This solution should work (I don't have Postgres installed here), but you may want to optimize it for large datasets; use indexes, statistics, etc... (the usual).

```
SELECT DISTINCT games.game_id FROM games INNER JOIN cards ON games.game_id = cards.game_id  WHERE games.current_player_id is NULL and games.game_id in (SELECT DISTINCT game_id FROM GAME_VIEWS WHERE user_id != 666) and cards.author_id != 666 GROUP BY games.game_id ORDER BY cards.created_at DESC
```

Again, swap "666" with the actual id.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood what I want. I want to find games, which meets all whose rules at once.